# Interact with the new Outlook for Windows app from .NET Framework/C#?

Tags: c#, outlook, office365

We have several applications running on .NET Framework 4.8 (C#) WinForms and WPF who access the Outlook desktop application on Windows via the known COM interop methods.

For example allowing us to prepare and opening a mail dialog in Outlook, so that a customer can continue there for sending the email using the local Outlook client.

[image]

Now a lot of people seem to switch to the new Outlook for Windows app.

When looking at the documentation COM add-ins will not be supported.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/getting-started-with-the-new-outlook-for-windows-656bb8d9-5a60-49b2-a98b-ba7822bc7627

[image]
[image]

COM add-ins will not be supported, which makes us believe that accessing the new Outlook for Windows app via COM interop will also not work (we can't get it working).

**Question:**

How do we access/interact with the new Outlook for Windows app from C# .NET Framework (WinForms/WPF) as we did with the regular Outlook desktop application (e.g. opening an email dialog)?

Comment: vote for the feature: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/21fea1cd-ec1f-ee11-a81d-0022484cae1d

Answer (score 0):

You can't - the new Outlook (Monarch) does not have any API besides web addins.

Keep in mind however, that the new Outlook is designed to be a replacement for Windows Mail and Windows Calendar, not the desktop Outlook, which is designed to be used in a corp environment.

Comment: then why does the "try the new outlook" button shows up in the current desktop Outlook and replaces it? Support phone is ringing hot with people who "tried" that button and now apps are broken.
Vote for it: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/21fea1cd-ec1f-ee11-a81d-0022484cae1d

Comment: Because they are trying to get more people to try the new Outlook. Apparently that is more effective than busstop ads.